# How firebase functions realtime-db triggers work with offline writes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

When some a series of write operations happens into Firebase Realtime DB when client is off-line,it's stored in the client and added into the db once it get connected.

The behavior of Firebase Functions will depending on, how it is written to the database. Will it just sync two DB's as a single write operation?
Or will it trigger all these write operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this.  You could try it yourself and verify the results on your own.

Each offline write to the exact same location in the database triggered a call to an onUpdate trigger at the same location.

However, you should not expect the triggers to be executed in any particular order.  There is no guarantee to the order of events delivered to a Cloud Functions trigger, and they may all be executed in parallel to some degree.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation @Doug-stevenson . Yeah. I should have tried. ;)

Comment: Is the same behaviour expected from `Firestore` ?